# Настроить отступ в html

Tags: visual-studio-code

Все привет, почему у меня у всех документов ХТМЛ таб - 4 пробела, а у некоторых 2 пробела?
Как исправить что бы везде было 4 пробела?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего срабатывает автоопределение, соответственно отступ столько пробелов, сколько используется в файле при его открытии. Поменять можно в статусбаре справа. А 4 пробела в веб уже давно устарели.

[image: скриншот]